# Android - How can we call some specific function when we click on app's home screen widget?

Tags: android, methods, widget, imageview, homescreen

I am making an app which will have a simple home screen widget( A simple imageview ).

What i want is to call some specific function like abc() or xyz() whenever i click on this imageview widget on my homescreen.

I have gone through so many examples but did not find a single one which could teach me this and 90% of the example were using TextView which has a function setTextViewText so TextView one is simple but how to call some specific function when we click on imageview or how to set onClick for ImageButton.

Please help and i would really appreciate if you provide me some piece of code.

Thanks.

```
public class Sample extends Activity {

public static final String TAG = "Sample";
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "I am HERE");
    Toast.makeText(this, "You Just Pressed Me", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

HEre is my update method -

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++)
     {
         int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Sample.class);
         //intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
         //intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
         RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.hswidget);
         views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);

         appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varundroid,

I don't think you can have a specific function launch on `Widget` click, but you can launch an `Activity` using a `PendingIntent`.  That's how mine is currently setup, and all the `Widge`t consist of is an `ImageView`.  Here is my implementation...

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="64dp" 
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        android:id="@+id/widget_image" 
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            /* Create the PendingIntent for a QuickNote */
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemEdit.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

         // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_provider);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_image, pendingIntent);

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current App Widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget `AndroidManifest.xml`!

```
    <receiver android:name=".WidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
           android:resource="@xml/appwidget_provider" />
    </receiver>
```

Comment: @willytate i tried your solution. I created a new activity and put one Log message and Toast in it so i can see how it works and i have added this code in my question above. But the problem is none of them(Log and Toast) has been displayed :-( please take a look at my code and tell me that what i did wrong. Thanks

Comment: @willytate yeah i did that too.

Comment: @willy whenever i press on my widget its showing me this message in logcat :- 04-22 00:36:25.423: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.varundroid.util.completetaskmanager/.Sample bnds=[252,421][348,517] }.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong with your code :[  the Sample `Activity` is also in the Manifest?

Comment: based on the `logcat` message, it looks like its attempting to start the `Activity`

Comment: @willy finally it starts working both Log and Toast has been displayed. Actually we both did not notice that i did not make a call to `super.onCreate(savedInstance);`. And 1 more thing after showing me the toast it showing me a black screen. what is this black screen for?

Comment: ohk i got it i did not set any layout for my sample activity so how to get rid of this black screen? should i call finish()?

Comment: call `finish()` or you could try to make the `Activity` transparent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Comment: Thanks a lot willytate for all your help. I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @willytate sorry for interrupting you again but i am facing a strange problem by making my activity transparent. whenever i click on my widget it performs the tasks but its also showing me black screen for few milliseconds. i tried hard to figure it out but did not find any leak. Any idea why its happening? thanks.

Comment: hmm, not sure.  i've never tried making an `Activity` transparent.  Perhaps  a `Thread`, `AsyncTask` or `Service` might better suite your application?  That way it would run in the background without needing to display anything at all.

Answer (score -5):

i don't understand what's your problem, but your problem mention above has very simple answer 
like
instantiating imageview by

```
ImageView imgView=findViewById(R.id.imgView);
```

and then set onClickListner to

```
imgView.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View view){
//call your functions
}
}
);
```

Comment: The question is about home screen widgets and pending intents